# ASP.NET connectionstring does not conform to specification

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, iis

Hy!

I am writing an asp.net application. I use entityframework 5 code first. I develop this site local, but I use the database of the webserver. When I publish this site to the webserver, I have to add the connection string in this way:

```
<add name="strConn" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=false;User ID=DBUSERNAME;Password=DBPASSWORD" />
```

instead of it:

```
 <add name="constringtwo" connectionString="Server=plumeria.arvixe.com,1433;Database=DBNAME;User Id=DBUSERNAME;Password=DBPASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

when I try to open my website I got an exception.
I wrote to the support I got this answer:

You appear to be trying to attach a database,

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-iAdmin.Web-20130813125200;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-iAdmin.Web-20130813125200.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I do not understand, because I have already deleted this connectionstring, how would it be?
I wrote the name of my connection string to the main datacontext, usercontext, and the websecurity.init.

thank you anticipation

the exception:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 109.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the
>   initialization string does not conform to specification starting at
>   index 109.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 109.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5314204
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) +59
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) +167
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key) +61
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   +66    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings
>   appConfigConnection) +122
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String
>   name, AppConfig config) +32
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +127
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
>   +13    System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +346    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateObjectContextForDdlOps()
>   +17    System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists() +36    iAdmin.Web.Filters.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor() +103
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The ASP.NET Simple Membership database
>   could not be initialized. For more information, please see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588]
>   iAdmin.Web.Filters.SimpleMembershipInitializer..ctor() +251
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6    System.Threading.LazyHelpers`1.ActivatorFactorySelector() +68
>
>   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target,
>   Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
>   System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(T& target, Boolean&
>   initialized, Object& syncLock) +106
>   iAdmin.Web.Filters.InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext
>   filterContext) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain) +69
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3b.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__35()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain) +489
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass3b.b*_35()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass37.b*_31(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +191
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +197
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +446
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) +302
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_17(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +382
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +317
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
>   requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_2(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +71
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +249
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: How do you publish to your server, are you deleting the files prior to deployment?

Comment: You might want to go on the server and manually delete your web.config prior to publishing. I've noticed certain deployment methods aren't really good at picking up changes in the web.config/app.config files

Comment: web deploy in vs 12
release remove additional files at destination

Comment: I watched, the connectionstring is good, on the server.
It was what the publish manager showed me

Comment: This is probably not it, but it is a place to look.  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files or
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files or
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files or 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: what is your app.config connection string name?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have a semicolon in your password?

For example, I can reproduce your exception by doing this:

```
new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=false;User ID=DBUSERNAME;Password=DBPASSWOR;D;")
```

But if I remove the semicolon from the password, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may be inheriting connection strings from a higher-level web.config or machine.config.  To avoid this, consider adding a `<clear/>` element to the `connectionStrings` configuration section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name=... />
    ...
```

Also from your stack trace, it looks like it's SimpleMembershipProvider that's trying to use the offending connection string.  You might want to remove SimpleMembershipProvider from your configuration, or configure it to use a different connection string.